# Spring roo entity dependency

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-roo

I'm working with Spring-Roo.

Is it possible to add field reference from a dependent package? I've added dependency at the begging of the script,

```
dependency add --groupId com.testroo.platform --artifactId platform --version 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

then I execute this while adding a jpa entity

```
field reference --fieldName city --type ~.domain.City --notNull
```

yet it complains with following.

```
The specified target '--type' does not exist or can not be found. Please create
this type first.
```

I thought spring-roo is smart enough to resolve it from dependency. Am I missing anything here? cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Spring roo and create a new project, you declare a top-level package name (assume com.foo entered) as a first step. **~** sign is used to refer to this package name later on.

So, in your case if you give the ~.domain.City as a parameter to the type argument, roo will look for it in com.foo.domain.City since ~ sign replaces top level package.

Short answer: If you want to add a field reference from a dependent package, give the full name of the class.